# T-SQL, assign values to multiple variable from the same column in one SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to manipulate variables into behaving like enums,

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ActionType
(
    ActionID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.ActionType 
    (ActionID, Name)
VALUES 
    (100, N'Product_Insert'), 
    (101, N'Product_Update'), 
    (102, N'Product_Delete')

DECLARE @ACTION_INSERT TINYINT,
        @ACTION_UPDATE TINYINT,
        @ACTION_DELETE TINYINT

SELECT  @ACTION_INSERT = ActionID, 
        @ACTION_UPDATE = ??, -- how would I do this properly?
        @ACTION_DELETE = ??  -- or is it possible?
FROM dbo.ActionType
WHERE Name LIKE 'Product_%'

-- Test result, which always returns null
SELECT @ACTION_INSERT, @ACTION_UPDATE, @ACTION_DELETE
```

I know I could use CURSOR, but is there a better approach to doing this without iteration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469318/t-sql-updating-more-than-one-variable-in-a-single-select

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete The accepted answer there was for multiple table columns; while in my case, I need these three variables be assigned with different values of different rows of one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pivot your data to get the result you want.

```
SELECT  @ACTION_INSERT = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Product_Insert' THEN ActionID END), 
        @ACTION_UPDATE = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Product_Update' THEN ActionID END),
        @ACTION_DELETE = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Product_Delete' THEN ActionID END)
FROM dbo.ActionType
WHERE Name LIKE 'Product_%'
```

Complete Code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ActionType
(
    ActionID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.ActionType 
    (ActionID, Name)
VALUES 
    (100, N'Product_Insert')
INSERT INTO dbo.ActionType 
    (ActionID, Name)
VALUES      
    (101, N'Product_Update') 
INSERT INTO dbo.ActionType 
    (ActionID, Name)
VALUES 
    (102, N'Product_Delete')

DECLARE @ACTION_INSERT INT,
        @ACTION_UPDATE INT,
        @ACTION_DELETE INT

SELECT  @ACTION_INSERT = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Product_Insert' THEN ActionID END), 
        @ACTION_UPDATE = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Product_Update' THEN ActionID END),
        @ACTION_DELETE = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Product_Delete' THEN ActionID END)
FROM dbo.ActionType
WHERE Name LIKE 'Product_%'

SELECT @ACTION_INSERT, @ACTION_UPDATE, @ACTION_DELETE
```

Comment: OK. Even though that's a bit longer but it nailed it. I would definitely pick this solution rather than having to hardcode the real values. Thanks!